# iframe and titles

Tags: html, iframe

I have two iframes on my html page, each with a height of 45%. How can I add a title above each iframe (simple text) and a space between the first iframe and the second title, such that they consume 10%. In other words, I don't what any scroll bar on the right.

Answer (score 0):

use  scrolling="no"

```
<iframe scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/modaloda/RQ62f/31/)

Answer (score -3):

to create a small one line space put a **`<br>`** tag, it doesn't need a close tag either e.g. **`</br>`** is not needed!

For a small title just put *`<h1>tile name here</h1>`* and for another *`<h2>title</h2>`*